# ASP.NET add a httphandler to edit downloaded file name

Tags: c#, asp.net, anchor, httphandler

I have in my project a page `DownloadDocument.aspx` and it's codebhind is `DownloadDocument.aspx.cs`

In my `DownloadDocument.aspx` i have an anchor which take a dynamic link like this:

```
<a id="downloadLink" runat="server"  style="margin:5px" 
href="<%# CONTENT_DIRECTORY_ROOT + document.Path %>">Download current file</a>
```

I want to add a httphandler to control the file name downloaded, How can i do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about using a generic handler (.ashx) for this?

You need to add loading specific information, like filename, contenttyp and the content itself. The sample should give you a good headstart.

```
public class GetDownload : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString["IDDownload"]))
        {
                context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=mydownload.zip");
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                byte[] rawBytes = // Insert loading file with IDDownload to byte array
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(rawBytes, 0, rawBytes.Length);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The generic handler is called from a URL, like this:

```
<a href="/GetDownload.ashx?IDDownload=1337">click here to download</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

it depends on type of file you are trying to download...because every request is gone through `HTTPHandler`'s `ProcessRequest`. and it's checks each and every request one by one..
You need to add any `HTTPHandler` to your project and need to add something like this in your `web.config`.

```
 <httpHandlers>
  <add path="*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.bmp,*.tif,*.tiff" verb="*" type="NameofYourHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

This will check your request for every `Image` type.. mentioned in `path` attribute

**Edit :**

```
<add verb="*" path="*DownloadDocument.aspx " type="NameofYourHandler"/>
```

Comment: i want it to support any file extention

Comment: see edit section...this will register your handler for your download page, for every request regardless of file types..

Comment: excuse Mayank, in the type i just put the handler name or the full path of the handler (i am new in .NET environment)

Comment: i still can't do it :( is there a link for a full example project?

Comment: For more info read these links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy(v=vs.71).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: In fact i don't now where to start... i haven't understand the concept [link](https://twitter.com/vervatovskis)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add 
   verb="POST"  
   path="*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.bmp,*.tif,*.tiff" 
   type="YourHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```