# Remove file extension on download using an ASP.NET HttpHandler?

Tags: asp.net, anchor, httphandler

I have stored file in my server, clients can download files via my page Home.aspx by clicking on an anchor, but i want to edit the original filename before launching download. How can i do it using an ASP.NET HttpHandler. Thanks in advance.

This is my anchor code:

```
 <% if (document.Path != null) { %>
                        <a id="downloadLink" runat="server" style="margin: 5px" href="<%# CONTENT_DIRECTORY_ROOT + document.Path %>">
                            <%= LanguageManager.GetValue("LABEL_DOWNLOAD") %></a>
                        <% } %>
```

Comment: Are the files static files in the file system or downloaded via a script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET add a httphandler to edit downloaded file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318715/asp-net-add-a-httphandler-to-edit-downloaded-file-name)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `RewritePath(newUrl)` method

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(sUrl)
```

Or you could use

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(sUrl)
```