# open byte[] pdf file using response.write( sever side actions are not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, response

i am using the following code to open the pdf byte[] file without saving it. It is working fine but after this action no other server side actions like button click are not working. Postback is not working.

```
    byte[] bytfile = Objects.GetFile(Convert.ToInt32(txtslno.Text.Trim()));
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+filename);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytfile.Length.ToString());
    Response.OutputStream.Write(bytfile, 0, bytfile.Length);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is working fine but after this action no other server side actions
>   like button click are not working.

Are you using your code inside a page or a control?

Use a generic handler (*.ashx) for your purpose. The code for downloading the pdf won't cause troubles for the application anymore.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12340735/225808 might be useful as a reference.

Comment: I am using it in the page

Comment: Try to use a generic handler instead

Answer (score 4):

Try this. It shoulld work.

```
byte[] bytfile = Objects.GetFile(Convert.ToInt32(txtslno.Text.Trim()));
Response.Clear();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytfile);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");
Response.Buffer = true;
ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

else try

```
Response.BinaryWrite(bytfile);
```

instead of

```
ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
```

in above code.

Comment: Still same problem. Do you any other idea to overcome this problem.

Comment: @Nathiya Is your button used in `UpdatePanel` `Trigger`?